# Zend Framework on multiple domains

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to run Zend Framework on multiple domains. On 1 domain I have the entire application with 2 different application.ini's one for each domain.
On the other domain I only copied the public folder. But I can't seem to get the second domain running probarly something in the index.php hope you guys can help me.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../DOMAIN_WITH_APPLICATION_MAP/application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'development'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../../DOMAIN_WITH_APPLICATION_MAP/library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance ();
$loader->setFallbackAutoloader ( true );
$loader->suppressNotFoundWarnings ( false );

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application2.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

Comment: What does your vhost config look like?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to update your server configuration. If you are using apache, you will want to use ServerAlias which will allow you to map the content from the main domain to the alias domain. Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.mysite2.co.uk www.mysite3.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```